# Is there a Git URI scheme that lets me reference a file in a repo at a specific commit?

Tags: git, uri, url-scheme

The [git Resource Identifier Scheme](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/prov/git) lets me reference a specific git repository.

However, I'm looking for a URI scheme that lets me reference a specific file/folder, at a specific commit, in a specific git repo. For example, the figurative URI `git://github.com/torvalds/linux.git:usr/Makefile@a30d8a39f0571425a459816ed8680e987a2ff279` could be used to reference the file `usr/Makefile` in the repository `git://github.com/torvalds/linux.git` at commit `a30d8a39f0571425a459816ed8680e987a2ff279`. Is there a standard URI scheme that achieves this?

To be clear, I'm interested in a URI scheme that works for all git servers, not e.g. a HTTP URL that works for e.g. GitHub or GitLab only.

Comment: No, it depends on the platform. You'll have to use specific patterns for github, bitbucket, gitlab...

Comment: @RomainValeri do you know why that's the case? Since all of those platforms (github/bitbucket/gitlab) speak the Git protocol, it should be possible to use a Git client and the Git-specific URI to fetch the given file from the server using the Git protocol.

Comment: It's just what I observed. I'll let more advanced users explore/explain the *why*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any widely accepted way to do this, but here is a scheme that I proposed years ago: http://www.nuke24.net/docs/2014/GitObjectURIScheme.html.

Generally, the form is `x-git-object:ef967a26bcd39ca62dd687e929ba4eba0ae66e81`, which references the **object** identified by that Git hash (which in this case is the content of Linux's Makefile, but could otherwise be a commit or tree, which are not directly representable as strings/byte sequences).  That document also specifies ways to suggest a repository and to reference the latest on a named branch or a path within a tree or commit, so you could say `x-git-object:latest?branch=master&repository=git://github.com/torvalds/linux.git#Makefile` to reference the Makefile in the latest commit on the master branch, whatever it may be.

Comment: Thank you. Your proposal looks very sensible. I especially like the fact that you distinguish between a “reference to a specific version of a file” and “where to get said file”. As you point out, there may be multiple locations where the file is available.

Comment: I'm glad my idea from 2014 helped someone!  I've added a section with test vectors in case my wording about "encodings" and "objects represented by ..." was not totally clear.

Comment: more general: https://github.com/hash-uri/hash-uri

Answer (score 1):

Git itself isn't about files; it's about commits.  So the main Git commands are about talking to another repository and getting commits.  The URLs that Git understands are meant to achieve this, and they do, and that's where they stop.

There *is* [the `git archive` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), which—with `--remote url`—can extract an archive of some or all files from one *specific* commit, provided the server allows it.  This is not a specific *file* URL/URI, though: this is a Git command that reaches out to a Git server (which, again, normally provides *commits*) and then asks that Git server if it is willing to prepare a single commit, or subset thereof, as a tar or zip archive.  By providing the path of a single file as the subset, you *may* be able to extract a single file from a particular commit on a particular Git server.  But that's as far as Git goes towards achieving your goal—and the arguments you would provide to `git archive` are again not a URL/URI.

Answer (score 0):

The SoftWareHeritage initiave has defined an id (swhid) that may be used to uniquely identify elements in software archive.

It allows to point down to repository, folder, file and even lines.

see. https://docs.softwareheritage.org/devel/swh-model/persistent-identifiers.html#persistent-identifiers

Even if it isn't an URL, there are some resolver available or you can force the use of the "origin".

For private software (which will not exist on SWH), you can locally generate your own id using the CLI (https://www.softwareheritage.org/faq/?lang=fr#33_How_can_I_get_a_SWHID_for_my_software)